# can anyone tell me why my javascript clicks isnt working?

Tags: javascript, css

i am making a shopping cart, looking to change the quantities but cant work out why its not working. i have created two funtions, one to add quantities and one to take away. i want to apply this to multiple objects in my shopping cart. it works if i change the p tag to an id rather than a class but i want it to apply to multiple items

```html
<div class="controlpic">
  <img class="img" src="jsbook1.png">
  <button onClick="onClick2()">-</button>
  <p class="clicks">0</p>
  <button onClick="onClick()">+</button>
  <button class="addBasket">Add to Basket</button>
  <div>some text about this product</div>
</div>
```

```js
/* onclick function will add clicks for basket*/
var clicks1 = 0;

function onClick() {
    clicks1 += 1;
    document.getElementsByClassName("clicks").innerHTML = clicks1;
  }
  /* onclick function will take away clicks for basket*/
var clicks1 = 0;

function onClick2() {
  if (clicks1 > 0) {
    clicks1 -= 1;
    document.getElementsByClassName("clicks").innerHTML = clicks1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your problem

> it works if i change the p tag to an id rather than a class but **i want it to apply to multiple items**

### Your approach

It doesn't work, because you are trying to set property [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) on an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) that `document.getElementsByClassName("clicks")` returns, instead of setting it on every of those elements.

### Fix

Replace your `document.getElementsByClassName("clicks").innerHTML = clicks1` with:

```js
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('clicks'), function(element) {
  element.textContent = clicks1;
});
```

### Demo

Below demo contains many flaws, it only presents how to implement the above fix. Also, each quantity modifier (`+` or `-`) will update all counters. For solution to this, see section *Rewrite*.

```js
/* onclick function will add clicks for basket*/
var clicks1 = 0;

function onClick() {
    clicks1 += 1;
    [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('clicks'), function(element) {
      element.textContent = clicks1;
    });
  }
  /* onclick function will take away clicks for basket*/
var clicks1 = 0;

function onClick2() {
  if (clicks1 > 0) {
    clicks1 -= 1;
    [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('clicks'), function(element) {
      element.textContent = clicks1;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="controlpic">
  <img class="img" src="jsbook1.png">
  <button onClick="onClick2()">-</button>
  <p class="clicks">0</p>
  <button onClick="onClick()">+</button>
  <button class="addBasket">Add to Basket</button>
  <div>some text about this product</div>
</div>
```

### Comments

Few other notes about your code:

- Don't use inline `onclick` use `element.addEventListener('click', someFunction)`
- Rather than `innerHTML` in your case, you can use `textContent`. It's safer and faster.
- Defining `var clicks1 = 0` second time makes no difference in your code.

### Rewrite

- [Rewrite of the same functionality](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGgMOQ).
- Rewrite to match your case attached below:

```js
function setQuantityModifier(element) {
  'use strict';
  var quantity = element.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('clicks')[0];
  element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    'use strict';
    if (element.value === '+') {
      quantity.textContent = parseInt(quantity.textContent) + 1;
    }
    else if (parseInt(quantity.textContent) > 0) {
      quantity.textContent = parseInt(quantity.textContent) - 1;
    }
  });
}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.controlpic > input'), setQuantityModifier);
```

```html
<div class="controlpic">
  <img class="img" alt="ADDME" src="jsbook1.png"/>
  <input type="button" value="&ndash;"/>
  <p class="clicks">0</p>
  <input type="button" value="+"/>
  <button class="addBasket">Add to Basket</button>
  <div>some text about this product</div>
</div>

<div class="controlpic">
  <img class="img" alt="ADDME" src="jsbook2.png"/>
  <input type="button" value="&ndash;"/>
  <p class="clicks">0</p>
  <input type="button" value="+"/>
  <button class="addBasket">Add to Basket</button>
  <div>some text about this product</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, noted. I have applied this to multiple items and it alters all quantities rather than keeping it individual

Comment: @Nbarnett: Take a look at [this example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGgMOQ) I've made, where it functions properly. In a second I'll rewrite your code to address that issue.

Answer (score 3):

#### The problem

The problem in your code is that [**`getElementsByClassName`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [**`HTMLCollection`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which is similar to (but not the same as) an array.

Instead of changing the `innerHTML` of your `HTMLCollection`, you should change the `innerHTML` the element(s) in your `HTMLCollection`.

---

#### The solution

If you only have one element with the class "clicks", you can just replace ...

```
document.getElementsByClassName("clicks").innerHTML = clicks1;
```

... with ...

```
document.getElementsByClassName("clicks")[0].innerHTML = clicks1;
```

... and everything will work just fine.

If you need to support multiple elements, you'll have to loop over those elements :

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('clicks'), function(clicks) {
    clicks.textContent = clicks1;
});
```

---

#### A demo

```js
var clicks1 = 0;

function onClick() {
    clicks1 += 1;
    [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('clicks'), function(clicks) {
        clicks.textContent = clicks1;
    });
}

function onClick2() {
    if (clicks1 > 0) {
        clicks1 -= 1;
        [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('clicks'), function(clicks) {
            clicks.textContent = clicks1;
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="controlpic">
  <img class="img" src="jsbook1.png">
  <button onClick="onClick2()">-</button>
  <p class="clicks">0</p>
  <button onClick="onClick()">+</button>
  <button class="addBasket">Add to Basket</button>
  <div>some text about this product</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Question's author explicitly asked for solution to run on every element from that HTMLCollection

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array (as you see getElement**s**, which is plural). You can either do `document.getElementsByClassName('clicks')[0].innerHTML` or you can use `document.querySelector('.clicks').innerHTML`

EDIT: for updating multiple elements with class name, you can use (based on @tymeJV's comment):

```
var clicks = document.getElementsByClassName('clicks');
for(var i = 0; i < clicks.length; ++i) {
    clicks[i].innerHTML = "...";
}
```

I personally like using `document.querySelectorAll('.clicks')` for any matchings (whether it is a class, id, or attribute).

Comment: I would add - to set the `innerHTML` for all of these elements returned, you can do a loop: `for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) { //set elems[i]`

Comment: Actually, `document.getElementsByClassName` doesn't return an array. It returns an `HTMLCollection`, which is similar to (but not the same as) an array. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection.

Comment: Also, question's author explicitly asked for solution that will run on every element from that HTMLCollection

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/30/

Add an id to `<p class="clicks" id="clicks">0</p>`

And insert text with `document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = clicks1;`

Also remove the second `var clicks1 = 0;` because you only need to declare a variable once.